# Elasticsearch Prefixfilter special character not working

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, ongr

I used ongr-elasticsearch bundle in php and wanted to add a PrefixFilter. 
When I add a slash at the front of the prefix it dont work. 
Here the query I build in ElasticSearch HQ Plugin:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "prefix": {
          "path": "/cmf"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

FXIED: need to use an custom pathAnalyzer to use queries

Answer (score 1):

Escape the forward slash

```
"prefix": {
  "path": "\/cmf"
}
```

Comment: sorry did forget to use an own analyzer for path.